# How to enable divs when clicking on the particular div with angular2?

Tags: css, angular, typescript

Here is my component.

```
    <div class="search-dropdown calender-dropdown ">
        <div class="search-dropdown-tabs-wrp">
            <ul class="search-dropdown-tabs">
                <li>
                    <a class="search-dropdown-tabs-active">Today</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>Tomorrow</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>This weekend</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>This week</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>Next week</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>This month</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content-area">
            <ul class="tab-content-area-active">
                <div class="row">
                   this is the first tab
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, Output,EventEmitter} from '@angular/core'; 
@Component({
    moduleId:module.id,
    selector: 'calendar',
    templateUrl: './calendar.component.html'
})
export class CalendarComponent{
   @Output() onDatePicked: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();  
  public fromDate:Date = new Date();    
  public toDate:Date = new Date();
  public closed : boolean;
  private events:Array<any>;
  private tomorrow:Date;
  dates = { startDate: this.fromDate, endDate: this.toDate , closed : this.closed};
  private afterTomorrow:Date;
  private formats:Array<string> = ['DD-MM-YYYY', 'YYYY/MM/DD', 'DD.MM.YYYY', 'shortDate'];
  private format = this.formats[0];
  private dateOptions:any = {
    formatYear: 'YY',
    startingDay: 1
  };
  private opened:boolean = false; 

  public pickDate( ): void {
    this.dates = { startDate: this.fromDate, endDate: this.toDate , closed : false};
    this.onDatePicked.emit(this.dates);
 }   
  public closeComponent() : void{
    this.dates.closed = true;
  }
```

How can i enable 2nd tab-content when tomorrow is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, Output,EventEmitter} from '@angular/core'; 
@Component({
    moduleId:module.id,
    selector: 'calendar',
    templateUrl: './calendar.component.html'
})
export class CalendarComponent{
   @Output() onDatePicked: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();  
  public fromDate:Date = new Date();    
  public toDate:Date = new Date();
  public status: string = "today"
  public closed : boolean;
  private events:Array<any>;
  private tomorrow:Date;
  dates = { startDate: this.fromDate, endDate: this.toDate , closed : this.closed};
  private afterTomorrow:Date;
  private formats:Array<string> = ['DD-MM-YYYY', 'YYYY/MM/DD', 'DD.MM.YYYY', 'shortDate'];
  private format = this.formats[0];
  private dateOptions:any = {
    formatYear: 'YY',
    startingDay: 1
  };
  private opened:boolean = false; 

  public pickDate( ): void {
    this.dates = { startDate: this.fromDate, endDate: this.toDate , closed : false};
    this.onDatePicked.emit(this.dates);
 }   
  public closeComponent() : void{
    this.dates.closed = true;
  }
```

**component.html**

```
    <div class="search-dropdown calender-dropdown ">
        <div class="search-dropdown-tabs-wrp">
            <ul class="search-dropdown-tabs">
                <li>
                    <a (click)="status='today'" class="search-dropdown-tabs-active">Today</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a (click)="status='tomorrow'">Tomorrow</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>This weekend</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>This week</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>Next week</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>This month</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content-area">
            <ul class="tab-content-area-active" *ngIf="status=='today'">
                <div class="row">
                   this is the first tab
                </div>
            </ul>
            <ul class="tab-content-area-active" *ngIf="status=='tomorrow'">
                <div class="row">
                   this is the second tab
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

You can create a variable in that keeps the data about what you want to display. You can do something like `(click)="state='tomorrow'"`. In your template you can use an `*ngIf` to show or hide certain parts like `*ngIf="state=='tomorrow'"`.

Comment: you have any sample?

Comment: can you copy your logic part of the component?

Comment: How are you using it then? You need a component.ts with the @component decorator to use it as an angular component.

Comment: yes yes what i meant was , i have a empty component.ts. ok will update with the question

Comment: Updated the solution. Check the status:string variable in the component.ts and how it's used in component.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135266/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-zanattman).